# как получить данные с callback_data в python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

```
def funcforInline(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    IKeyboard = (InlineKeyboardButton('text', callback_data='text'),InlineKeyboardButton('Feedback', callback_data='feed'),
        InlineKeyboardButton('[General Menu]', callback_data='menu'))
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([IKeyboard])
    update.message.reply_text(text='Choose an option', reply_markup=reply_markup)
```

как получить данные `callback_data` с `InlineKeyboardButton` или же `InlineKeyboardMarkup`?

Дело заключается в том, что я хочу использовать данные полученные с `InlineKeyboardButton` для перенаправления в другую функцию с учетом выбранной кнопки

Comment: Покажите, какой код у вас уже есть, как сделана клавиатура и какие handler вы используете

Answer (score 2):

```
`pyTelegramBotAPI`
# Inline keyboard 
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'text':
       print('press button "text"')
    elif call.data == 'menu':
       print('"press button menu"')
```

`python-telegram-bot`

```
keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
             InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')],

          [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')]]
reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

query = update.callback_query
query.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: {}".format(query.data))
```

*We insert query.data into the string, which is the data we defined in the keyboard, so the number 1, 2 or 3*

Comment: извините за мой французский, но а что делает `@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)` и точно ли это все для библиотеки `python-telegram-bot` а не для `pyTelegramBot`?

Comment: Декоратор `@bot.callback_query_handler` принимает в именованном аргументе `func` анонимную функцию, возвращающую `True`. это для `pyTelegramBot`, а для `python-telegram-bot` https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/InlineKeyboard-Example#button (We insert `query.data` into the string, which is the data we defined in the keyboard, so the number 1, 2 or 3.)